# When using a block in beamer class the output is giving two overlapped box

Tags: beamer, block

The output of this code gives two overlapped boxes. What is wrong?

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%\setbeamersize{text margin left=0.5cm,text margin right=0.5cm}


\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Warsaw}
  % or ...

  \setbeamercovered{transparent}
  % or whatever (possibly just delete it)
}


\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% or whatever

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
% or whatever

\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
% Or whatever. Note that the encoding and the font should match. If T1
% does not look nice, try deleting the line with the fontenc.
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
%\newcommand{\K}{\mathbb{K}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}
\title[\textbf{Á}lgebra \textbf{L}inear e \textbf{G}eometria \textbf{A}nalítica] % (optional, use only with long paper titles)
{\textbf{Á}lgebra \textbf{L}inear e \textbf{G}eometria \textbf{A}nalítica}
\usetheme{Copenhagen} 
%\subtitle
%{}

\author[Rui Gonçalves] % (optional, use only with lots of authors)
{Rui~Gonçalves\inst{1}}

\institute[Universidade do Porto] % (optional, but mostly needed)
{
  \inst{1}%
  Departamento de Engenharia Civil\\
  Universidade do Porto
  }
% - Use the \inst command only if there are several affiliations.
% - Keep it simple, no one is interested in your street address.

\date[Porto, 2021] % (optional, should be abbreviation of conference name)
%{Conference on Fabulous Presentations, 2003}
% - Either use conference name or its abbreviation.

% Delete this, if you do not want the table of contents to pop up at
% the beginning of each subsection:
\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>{Outline}
    \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection]
  \end{frame}
}



\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Sumário}
  \tableofcontents
  % You might wish to add the option [pausesections]
\end{frame}

\section{Apresentação}

\begin{frame}
Uma relação $R$ num conjunto $A$ diz-se:
\begin{block}{lista}
\begin{itemize}
\item[1] Reflexiva se $(\forall x\in A) xRx.$
\item[2] Simétrica se $(\forall x,y\in A) xRy\Rightarrow yRx.$
\item[3] Anti-Simétrica se $(\forall x,y\in A) xRy\wedge yRx\Rightarrow x=y.$
\item[4] Transitiva se $(\forall x,y,z\in A) xRy\wedge yRz\Rightarrow xRz.$
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
\end{frame}

\appendix
\section<presentation>*{\appendixname}
\subsection<presentation>*{For Further Reading}

\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
  \frametitle<presentation>{For Further Reading}

  \begin{thebibliography}{10}

  \beamertemplatebookbibitems
  % Start with overview books.

  \bibitem{Author1990}
    A.~Author.
    \newblock {\em Handbook of Everything}.
    \newblock Some Press, 1990.


  \beamertemplatearticlebibitems
  % Followed by interesting articles. Keep the list short.

  \bibitem{Someone2000}
    S.~Someone.
    \newblock On this and that.
    \newblock {\em Journal of This and That}, 2(1):50--100,
    2000.
  \end{thebibliography}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Here is the image of error

[image]

Comment: Can you show the error on output picture, please?

Comment: thanks for your answer.

Comment: I putted the figure but is not showing at leat for me. Can you see it? It's ok, just have to copy and paste to the browser.

Comment: You want to have 2 or one block on one page?

Comment: YOUR MWE works fine, but it has only one block in third frame. BTW, you not need to load `graphicx`, it is already loaded by `beamer`. Also better is to use `utf8` input encoding /`inputenc`/  than `latin1`.

Comment: Hi. In almost all cases I just use one block per frame. The problem is that the output of a single block is gives the correct and expected block overlapped with a not wanted second one with the same content in gray.